# Use a Switch or Router for PoE on VOIP system

Tags: router, switch, voip

I have a question regarding if a switch or router is the way to go in my situation. We have a modem through Comcast that only has one available port on it right now and we are getting a VOIP system through RingCentral. We are receiving 5 phones that support PoE, most routers I am finding either don't support PoE or they only have 4 ports on them. Can I plug the Switch into the open port on the Modem and have all of them work like they should?

Comment: If the phones are to run on the same network as the other devices, this should be fine in theory.  However without knowing the design, devices (makes/models), or actual current setup, we can't really answer this definitively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switches are where you typically find PoE especially in enterprise-grade equipment.  **You should have no issue extending your LAN with a switch on an available port on your cable modem, but you really should have a router/firewall function sitting between your LAN and the WAN from your modem to protect your network.**

You can confirm that you are directly connecting your LAN to the modem by the presence of public IP addresses which is a good way to get hacked.  A firewall provides a baseline of protection that you seem to be lacking now.  Be aware that the firewall (on your router) will be providing a NAT function that doesn't always play nicely with SIP packets from your VoIP.  You may need a firewall capable of handling SIP properly or a VoIP system that can support STUN.